# Google Cloud: attaching GPU to existing instance

Tags: gpu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've got an Compute Engine instance with 1 GPU attached.
After some time, I increased my quota to have 2 instances available. 
Is it possible to attach the second GPU to this existing instance?
Do I have to create the instance again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add more GPUs to an existing instance via the UI or API. However, to do so, you need to stop the VM first, edit the vm (change the number of gpus for example) and then start the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the option (when trying to edit a stopped instance) at the moment.

If you choose to create a new instance, consider taking a snapshot of your current disk and then create the new instance using that snapshot - that can make the process easier.